# Log de Tentativa de Acesso ao Banco (Oracle 11G)

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Temos um Oracle 11G aqui na empresa. Semana passada algum engraçadinho tentou acessar por mais de 10 vezes com usuário ou senhas incorretos. 
Pesquisei e estou pesquisando alguma forma de guardar Logs de acesso no banco, como IP da máquina que tentou conectar. Estou estudando sobre o Listener do Oracle para saber se ele possui essa função.
Alguém conhece alguma configuração no Oracle para guardar estes dados?

Comment: dentro do proprio log do oracle tem esses dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo estou encaminhando um link com todas as informação de logs do oracle aonde você juntamente com o DBA podem resolver este problema.

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14007/servlog.htm)